# Ошибка Broken pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

Есть класс

```
class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = None

    async def resolve(self):
        if self.__session is None:
            return
        await self.__session.close()

    async def request(url):
        if self.__session is None:
            self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        resp = await self.__session.request(url)
        try:
            r_ = await resp.json()
        except:
            r_ = await resp.text()
        return r_
```

В тесте я делаю так:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1():
    timeout = 3
    client = AsyncClient()
    _, _ = await client.request('0.0.0.0:8080/test')
    time.sleep(timeout)
    _, _ = await client.request('0.0.0.0:8080/test')
```

В таком случае, всё ок. Но мне потребовалось поставить таймату на побольше, так как метод запускает поток. И если я ставлю 10 секунд (на самом деле, 5 достаточно), то получаю следующую ошибку на втором вызове:

```
../../anaconda3/envs/deps-backend/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:504: in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
../../anaconda3/envs/deps-backend/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py:847: in start
    message, payload = await self._protocol.read()  # type: ignore  # noqa
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7efe394f8750>

    async def read(self) -> _T:
        if not self._buffer and not self._eof:
            assert not self._waiter
            self._waiter = self._loop.create_future()
            try:
>               await self._waiter
E               aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

../../anaconda3/envs/deps-backend/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py:591: ClientOSError
```

Comment: Разве для `async` не нужен свой таймаут? не `time.sleep`, а другой?

Comment: @gil9red а какая разница? Насколько я понимаю, asynctimeout лочит только конкретный гринтред. А timeout -- весь эвент луп. На что это здесь влияет?

Comment: @gil9red это влияет. С ним работает. Но это не уменьшает важности вопроса